# Does dual-channel work only with an even number of RAM sticks?

Tags: motherboard, dual-channel

I have noticed that on the ASUS P5QL Pro motherboard the BIOS says "Dual Channel Asymmetric Mode" during POST. The motherboard has three 2GB Kingston ValueRAM 800 MHz DIMMs populated in the first 3 slots from the CPU socket. I have not run any benchmarks to verify that dual-channel is somehow being used, but I believed that dual-channel has to have an even number of sticks (and for triple channel, a multiple of 3).

Another example is the Intel DX58SO motherboard; it has four DIMM slots, yet it's an LGA 1366 motherboard which does triple-channel. Apparently triple-channel still works with four DIMMs, instead of falling back to dual-channel.

What does the BIOS' POST message mean in those case? Is dual-channel really used for the first two DIMMs, with the other one being an odd one in single-channel mode?

Answer (score 0):

Well your motherboard supports Core 2 Duos, so its memory controller is going to be a dual channel.  Since you have three, the first and third are dual channeled and the second one is asymmetric.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is incorrect. Dual-channel usually requires only that the same amount of RAM be placed on each channel. If you have two 1GB sticks on one channel and a 2GB stick on the other, then each channel has the same amount of RAM and dual-channel is supported.